# When I started with the beginning of the article title number, gives a 404 error

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, permalinks

in wordpress, when I started with the beginning of the article title number, gives a 404 error.
Not problem I used:

```
Title: Hello World
Permalink: example.com/hello-world
```

But problem is at this:

```
Title: 2 Hello World
Permalink: example.com/2-hello-world
```

My title is "2 Hello World" or "23 Hello World" or "any number Hello World".. So permalink is "2-hello-world" or "23-hello-world".. Click permalink: its 404 no found. But, when My title was example: "Hello World 2", no problem!

Comment: Can u explain what is title number?

Comment: My title is "2 Hello World" or "23 Hello World" or "`any number` Hello World".. So permalink is "2-hello-world" or "23-hello-world".. Click permalink: its 404 no found. But, when My title was example: "Hello World 2", no problem!.

Comment: I tried the same thing. It is working fine. Try to change the permalink to default, then save it. Again change it post name as it is now and save it. Sometimes permalinks don't get updated. Try updating permalink again.

Comment: Hi. I tried your said. I Updated permalinks. But not change problem. Its just same. Not problem in Default permaliks (/?p=123) its work. but in /%postname%/, same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I solved my problem. Problem is web.config codes..

I chanced my code thats, problem solved:

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^index\.php$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+)" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="wp-includes/ms-files.php?file={R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}wp-admin/" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 5" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 6" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 7" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```